Laplace transform on boundary condition of PDE results in D::ivar warning
Bug introduced in 14.0, persisting through 14.1.

I am trying to convert my boundary condition to its Laplace transform as in this picture:

I have tried to do so using the following code:
(* Step 1: Define the boundary condition PDE (S-6) *)
bc1PDE = (Vc/(Z*Rg*T)) D[pc[t], t] == diff * A * (D[c[z, t], z] /. z -> 0);

(*bc1PDEf[y_] := (Vc/(Z*Rg*T)) D[pc[t], t] == diff * A * (D[c[z, t], z] /. z -> y);*)
(* Step 2: Apply the Laplace Transform to the boundary condition *)
boundaryConditionS6 = LaplaceTransform[bc1PDE, t, s];

(* Step 3: Dividing Both sides by A*)
eqManipulated = DivideSides[boundaryConditionS6, A];

(* Step 4: Assuming A != 0 *)
eqManipulated = Simplify[eqManipulated, A != 0];

(* Step 5: Substitute Vc/A with h *) (*Where h = Vc/A*)
boundaryConditionS6 = eqManipulated /. (Vc/A) -> h;

(* Step 6: Display in TraditionalForm *)
boundaryConditionS6 // TraditionalForm

and I got this incorrect output after a D::ivar warning:

Any advice?

Is there any solution for this? can I go back to the previous version?

I've found a fix for the bug, see the updated answer.

This is a bug introduced in v14.0 and persisting through v14.1. (I noticed this in the chat shortly after the release of 14.0 BTW. ) Minimal sample reproducing the issue:
LaplaceTransform[Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0], t, s]

Behavior of v14.0 and v14.1:

Behavior of earlier version:

Notice the behavior of D has changed, too. (Not surprising, because otherwise an infinite loop will be generated. ) Minimal sample:
D[LaplaceTransform[u[t, x], t, s], x]

Behavior of v14.0 and v14.1:

Behavior of earlier version:

"OK, then how to fix this?" Sadly there doesn't seem to be an easy way to patch LaplaceTransform, because GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@LaplaceTransform shows the core part of LaplaceTransform is kernel function. Thanks to the hint from Silvia in the comment below, I've found a way to bring back the old behavior of LaplaceTransform.
By observing the output of
Trace[LaplaceTransform[Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0], t, s], TraceInternal -> True]

We can see a GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode function has been used. Further checking the function with
LaplaceTransform; (* This line is necessary if it's a fresh kernel. *)
GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions@GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode

or
LaplaceTransform; (* This line is necessary if it's a fresh kernel. *)
ClearAttributes[GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode, ReadProtected];
Internal`$ContextMarks = False;
DownValues@GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode

We can see a defective transformation rule:

Though this rule can be useful in some cases as shown in your subsequent question, the bug is annoying enough, so let's remove it:
LaplaceTransform; (* This line is necessary if it's a fresh kernel. *)    
ClearAttributes[GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode, {ReadProtected, Protected}]

dv = DownValues@GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode;

pos = Complement[
  Intersection[First /@ Position[dv[[All, 1]], _Derivative], 
   First /@ Position[dv, _D]], First /@ Position[dv, DiracDelta]]
(* {14} *)

DownValues@GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode = Delete[dv, pos];

LaplaceTransform[Derivative[0, 1][u][t, 0], t, s]


D is relatively easy to patch (but notice D should be patched together with LaplaceTransform using the code above, otherwise a dead loop will be generated!):
Unprotect[D];
D[HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, b__], c__] := LaplaceTransform[D[a, c], b]
Protect[D];

D[LaplaceTransform[u[t, x], t, s], x]


You may save the two pieces of code in your SystemOpen@"init.m".

Try GenerateConditions`TopLevelCode // PrintDefinitions ;)

@Silvia Oh actually I saw this function when Traceing the code, but didn't notice its importance... Thanks for pointing out! The answer is updated.
